# how to prevent html element moving when resizing browser window?(how to fix an elemnt in an exact point in a webpage)

Tags: html, css

I’m a beginner in front-end web development. I was trying a simple responsive page. In this project, I have a problem with that candle holder image, this image is size-responsive; it will resize when the browser window resizes but, the position of the image will change when the browser window gets smaller and the candle holder will move respect to its full-screen position.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>form</title>
    <style>
        body{margin: 0px;}
        #main{
            background-color: hsl(308, 62%, 39%);
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            position: relative;
        }
        #blendaText{
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 3.5vw;
            top:50px;
            left: 25px;
        }

        #form-container{
            background-color: white;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 70vw;
            float: right;
            border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
        }
        #candleImage{
            position: relative;
            top:200px;
            left: 200px;
            width:30%;
            height: auto;
        }
        #form{
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
        input{width: 90%;}
        input[type="submit"]{margin-left: 5px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="main">
            <p id="blendaText"> Blenda allows <br> you to imagine 3D </p>
            <img id="candleImage" src="candle.png" alt="candle holder">
            <div id="form-container">
                <form id="form">
                    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""><br>
                    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value=""><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                  </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: full screen browser window]
[image: smaller browser window]

So I tried a search in Stackoverflow and found these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841845/prevent-div-from-moving-while-resizing-the-page) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009538/how-to-prevent-html-element-moving-when-resizing-window) similar questions but their answers didn’t work for me. I also tried different positioning; absolute, relative, fixed, and sticky but also didn’t work.
[here's](https://ibb.co/DQbwWyh) the candle image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to use dynamic units for placing the image in your #candleImage styles.

Here's the updated styles:

```css
#candleImage {
                position: relative;
                top: 20vh;
                left: 15vw;
                width: 30%;
                height: auto;
            }
```

Comment: can you describe why it work that way? what is the concept behind it?

Comment: Relative units in CSS, such as vw (viewport width) and vh (viewport height), adapt to the dimensions of the viewer's screen. So, if an element is positioned 15 vw units from the left edge, it will always maintain that distance, regardless of the screen size. This ensures that the design remains consistent across various devices and screen resolutions.
@Sepehr

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of relative units / same ways you did for your left purple sidebar, refer to the changes to the new CSS for `#candleImage` selector below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>form</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
      }
      #main {
        background-color: hsl(308, 62%, 39%);
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
      }
      #blendaText {
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 3.5vw;
        top: 50px;
        left: 25px;
      }
      #form-container {
        background-color: white;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 70vw;
        float: right;
        border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
      }
      #candleImage {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10vh;
        left: 30vw;
        width: 30%;
        height: auto;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
      }
      #form {
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
      input {
        width: 90%;
      }
      input[type='submit'] {
        margin-left: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <p id="blendaText">
        Blenda allows <br />
        you to imagine 3D
      </p>
      <img
        id="candleImage"
        src="https://i.ibb.co/ZxJcXP5/candle.png"
        alt="candle holder"
      />
      <div id="form-container">
        <form id="form">
          <label for="fname">First name:</label><br />
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" /><br />
          <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br />
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="" /><br /><br />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a similar issue on the zoom-in zoom-out of the page.
The best solution is to use Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Flexbox will save your life in many future scenarios.
Otherwise, you can just create a table and fix your website structure with it.

Here is a first step with Flexbox that should work fine:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>form</title>
        <style>
            body{margin: 0px;}
            #main{
                display: flex; 
                flex-direction: row;
                align-items:stretch ;
                align-content:stretch;
                background-color: hsl(308, 62%, 39%);
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
            }
            #blendaText{
                color: white;
                font-size: 3.5vw;
                top:50px;
                left: 25px;
            }
            #form-container{
                flex-shrink: 3;
                background-color: white;
                height: 100vh;
                width: 70%;
                border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
            }
            #column{
                width: 30%;
             flex-shrink: 3;
            }
            #candleImage{
                position: relative;
                      margin-left:1vmin;
                height: 25vw;
            }
            #form{
                margin-left: 100px;
                margin-top: 100px;
            }
            input{width: 90%;}
            input[type="submit"]{margin-left: 5px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="main">
                <div id="column">  
                    <p id="blendaText"> Blenda allows <br> you to imagine 3D </p>
                    <img id="candleImage" src="https://i.ibb.co/ZxJcXP5/candle.png" alt="candle holder">
                </div>  
                <div id="form-container">
                    <form id="form">
                        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""><br>
                        <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value=""><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                      </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```